# Linked-List destructor

Tags: visual-c++, dynamic, linked-list, destructor

I am working with linked-lists and I was wondering what would be a good destructor
for a linked-list to prevent memory leaks. Since every time I traverse the list I create a node pointer to print,append,find,delete,insert.

Comment: Your question would be easier answered if you explained the problem better. While linked lists are a common structure there are many implementations too... and I am unclear what you classify as "good". Avoiding memory leaks how/where?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback , anyway I have found my answer to my problem in another post.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a node and use that for all your findings. You set it to root and traverse the list using that.

Comment: I am saying instead of creating a node each time you traverse the list, create one node and use that everytime. Don't delete it after you are done. just reuse it.